# How to manipulate an unknown color with sass

Tags: sass

Maybe this is beyond the scope of SASS but is there a way to grab a current color (declared somewhere else) and manipulate it?

For example:

```
mycustomcolor {
     background-color: (lighten( $ORIGINALCOLOR[not declared in my style sheets], 1.6% );
}
```

Comment: Not possible :(

Comment: Use Variables for that